# adding the class active dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, django

## html

```
 <ul class="nav">
   <li class=""><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

## script

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location=='/home/'){
       $('.nav li:first').appendClass('active');
     }
//---and similarly for other divs or 
  });
```

## doubt

is there any other simpler way to accomplish this other than using the django code embedded to declare the class conditionally , thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean 'other then using the django code embedded'? You can achieve this using a template tag, but I'm not sure if that is what you are trying to avoid?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony he meant the current page, I guess.

Comment: Yea, it seems this doesn't relate to django at all

Comment: yea i meant that i could use django template code to add class active to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [this simple template tag](https://snipt.net/jonbiddle/simple-navigation-template-tag/):

```
# app/templatetags/menu.py
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def active(request, pattern):
    import re
    if re.search(pattern, request.path):
        return ' class="active"'
    return ''

# your_template.html
{% load menu %}
<ul class="nav">
    <li{% active request "^/home/$" %}><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li{% active request "^/about/$" %}><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
    <li{% active request "^/contact/$" %}><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

There are several improvements possible, notably reducing the amount of repetition by using `reverse()` in the templatetag instead of requiring the URL regex as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.nav li:first').appendClass('active');
```

instead of this, try

```
 $('.nav li:first').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are fewer links I would use like below,

```
var links = ['/home/', '/about/', '/contact/' ];

$(document).ready(function(){
   var idx = $.inArray(window.location, links);
   $('.nav li').eq(idx).addClass('active');
});
```

if you have lot of links.. then try below..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var curLink = window.location;

   $('.nav li').each(function () {
      if (curLink == $(this).find('a').attr('href')) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: but what if there are like 100 links

Comment: @user1437670 You are using window.location, the href attributes have absolute pathes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of using `.appendClass(...)` :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     if(window.location=='/home/'){
        $('.nav li:first').addClass('active');
     }
 });
```

Then If you have more elements from different types as you wrote and want them to have the `.active` class, do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //x: group all 'div' elements.
    var x = $('div');
    //y: group all 'p' elements
    var y = $('p');
    //All elements:
    var combined = x.add(y);

    if(window.location=='/home/'){
      combined.addClass('active');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `window.location` really matches your `href` attributes, which I doubt it does, you can just select them directly :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav li a[href="'+window.location+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});​
```